# Stretch image to viewport maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: css, viewport, aspect-ratio, stretch

Current setup:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Fullscreen image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/187205892989648897/251689220819648513/e448455be034a36f6e09b46e671bdfd1.png" alt="Loading..." id="slide" />
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Demo of how I want things to look like: https://jsfiddle.net/fu3bL2Lx/1/

When you stretch and resize your browser, the image will still stay dead centered vertically and horizontally, while also fitting inside the viewport, keeping its aspect ratio.

The problem here is, when I click on the white space around the image, I still get the `alert` triggered that was bound to the `img`

I'm pretty sure this could be solved with flexbox if not with just regular unset `display` value, but I'm not very knowledgeable of it.

Comment: Please provide relevant code for us to look at in the post.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your image is still occupying 100% of the viewport.

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
```

You actual image stays normal because of the `object-fit` property, MDN:

> The object-fit CSS property specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and width.

Containing means:

> The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element’s content box: its concrete object size is resolved as a contain constraint against the element’s used width and height.

This is the reason you can click on the whitespace around the image.

Comment: I have looked up what `object-fit` does on MDN prior to using it, but I don't know any better, so I went with it for the time being.